# Which is a good size of leg stent?

Tags: surgery

A stent is a small mesh tube that's used to treat narrow or weak arteries. Some stents are coated with medicine that is slowly and continuously released into the artery. These stents are called drug-eluting stents. The medicine helps prevent the artery from becoming blocked again. http://www.nhlbi.nih.gov/health/health-topics/topics/stents

What is the difference between big hollow stent and small hollow leg stent? Are there any side effects of big hollow stent?